# Yii2: Gridview EditableColumn invisible popover

Tags: php, yii2, hide

I am using *Kartik Gridview.* Unfortunately, when I create an **editable column**, it does *not show* the box to enter editable values. **That box is being hidden after the next row**, how can I fix this?

What happening???

[image: Issue]

What I expect

[image]

Here is my code

```
[
        // type of columns
        'class' => 'kartik\grid\EditableColumn',
        // data which is rendered from controller, use by its attribute
        'attribute' => 'note',
        'header' => 'Ghi chú',
        // vertical alignment
        'vAlign' => 'middle',
        // horizontal alignment
        'hAlign' => 'center',
        // edit field
        'editableOptions' => function ($model, $key, $index) {
            return [
                'name' => 'note', // this will be sent to controller to process
                'header' => 'Ghi chú',
                'asPopover' => true,
                'inputType' => \kartik\editable\Editable::INPUT_TEXTAREA,
                // appear above the text box
                'beforeInput' => '<h3 style="font-weight: bold">Thêm ghi chú về ứng viên này</h3>',
                // default value in the text box
                'value' => $model['note'] // in this case, $model is an array. For others, $model->employer_score
            ];
        },
        'format' => 'raw',
        // format of this column will display html code
        // 'format' => 'html',
    ],
```

Comment: Your code works for me correctly, https://imgur.com/a/M6b02u0 , you should check for any errors in the console on page load or when you click on the text to open the popup if there isnt any error in console then there might be some css that is conflicting and hiding the popover

Comment: In fact, It's a conflict between local CSS and plugin CSS. I've fixed it successfully!

Comment: except for some other CSS like auto disappear editable text field

Comment: hi @NgôVănQuyền i have same problem. Can you tell me how you fix the conflict? Thank's

Comment: @FedericoBenedetti It's a conflict between local CSS and plugin CSS. Just add some inline CSS to fix this!

Comment: Also, check asPopover with false or any other cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a conflict between local CSS and plugin CSS. Just add some inline CSS to fix this!